# React website not getting hosted on github

Tags: reactjs, github

I tried hosting my website on github but instead of showing me my website its showing me this page
[image: Getting Started with Create React App]

Link to github repo:
https://github.com/AfeefRaza/ecom-website

Comment: Under your [pages settings](https://github.com/AfeefRaza/ecom-website/settings/pages) do you have it pointed to the gh-pages branch?

Comment: @ZacAnger [No](https://github.com/AfeefRaza/ecom-website/actions/runs/3406156769/jobs/5664648522#step:3:3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the beta built-in Actions workflow to deploy your site. You'll need to change the line pointing to `main` to point to `gh-pages` instead. If using old version, which just has a dropdown menu allowing you to pick a branch, you need to change that to `gh-pages`.